# Loading stylesheet from parent window to iframe

Tags: jquery, iframe, cors

I'm trying to grab the stylesheet from the parent window, and apply the styles to the page within an iframe. The iframed page is on a separate domain(yes, this has to work around CORS).

jquery sitting on parent page

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.iframe-div').load(function(){
        $('#iframe-div')
            .contents().find("head")
            .append($('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">')
        );
    });
});
```

iframe:

```
<iframe src="player.html" class="iframe-div" width="800" height="400"></iframe>
```

Player.html should have the appended stylesheet applied to the header.

As an example, here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mattography/orfd5jcq/1/)

Comment: There is no element with ID `iframe-div` in your jsFiddle and iframe onload event isn't fired if window already loaded. BTW, domains must match. Here is your fixed jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/orfd5jcq/2/

Answer (score 0):

If you control both the parent and the child window, the parent can pass the url of the CSS file either as a ULR parameter to the iframe, or you could possibly use [window.postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.postMessage?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/window.postMessage) to send it from the parent to child.

Then you can add the css using the following code

```
var fileref=document.createElement("link")
fileref.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet")
fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/css")
fileref.setAttribute("href", filename)
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref)
```

(borrowed from http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/loadjavascriptcss.shtml)

I don't believe that the iframe can access anything in the parent window across domains, nor can the parent affect the iframe, so I believe this would be impossible if you can only put code in the iframe or the parent and not both.